# Error can not be run occurred

Tags: c++, eclipse, vector

I have a program developed by the Eclipse.

It is a code like the following.

```
class VectorClass
{
    private:
        vector<string> VectorTest;
    public:
        VectorClass()
        {
            VectorTest[0] = "TEST1";
            VectorTest[1] = "TEST2";
            VectorTest[2] = "TEST3";
        }
};
```

When you wrote code like this, I get the following error when you debug.

```
No source available for "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
 std::allocator<char> >::assign() at 0x3e0009dfd6"
```

So, I changed the code like the following.

```
class VectorClass
{
    private:
        vector<string> *VectorTest;
    public:
        VectorClass()
        {
            VectorTest = new vector<string>;
            VectorTest->at(0) = "TEST1";
            VectorTest->at(1) = "TEST2";
            VectorTest->at(2) = "TEST3";
        }
};
```

Then it became such an error.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check
```

And I was examined, but I do not know the cause.

Will the use is wrong.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: In both cases, your `vector` always has a size of 0.  Try `VectorTest.push_back("TEST1")` to add a new element.

Comment: Are you running in debug or release mode?

Answer (score 0):

Vectors don't work like arrays in all cases. An array has a fixed size, a vector can grow and shrink. Hence, although you can use the `operator[]` to assign elements to an array, you cannot use it to access elements of a vector beyond its current size.

You would need to use `push_back()` to put elements into the vector first, and then you can use `operator[]` to access/assign those elements. (You could also define the vector with a specific size.)

The following code should work:

```
VectorTest.push_back(string("TEST1"));
VectorTest[0] = "Change TEST1";
```

The difference here is that after the `push_back()`, vector has one element, so you can now access element at position 0.

Comment: @DrewDormann Of course. You posted the comment while I was editing to make that point more explicit. :)

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I am trying to nest in the vector variable.

Therefore, I thought the code such as the following.

```
class VectorClass
{
    private:
        vector< vector<string> > *VectorTest;
    public:
        VectorClass()
        {       
            VectorTest = new vector< vector<string> >(20);
            VectorTest->at(0) = new vector<string>(20);

            VectorTest->at(0)->at(0) = "TEST1";
            VectorTest->at(0)->at(1) = "TEST2";
            VectorTest->at(0)->at(2) = "TEST3";
        }
};
```

However, you can not successfully compile in this.

Should take any way in order to achieve this business?

Thanks for reading.